# How to add data from database into dynamic texbox in a table using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have created a dynamic table that user can add rows like example below.

[image]

The dynamic row created from below code:

```
<table id="newrow" style="display:none;">
    <tr style="background-color:#ffffff;">
        <td style="font-weight:bold;padding-left:5px;padding-top:0px;padding-bottom:0px;padding-right:0px;vertical-align:middle"></td>
        <td style="padding:0px">
            <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The TargetColor_U field is required." id="TargetInfo_#__TargetColor_U" name="TargetInfo[#].TargetColor_U" type="text" value="" />
            @*<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="TargetInfo[#].TargetColor_U" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>*@
            <input type="hidden" name="TargetInfo.Index" value=# />
        </td>
        <td style="padding:0px">
            <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The TargetColor_V field is required." id="TargetInfo_#__TargetColor_V" name="TargetInfo[#].TargetColor_V" type="text" value="" />
            @*<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="TargetInfo[#].TargetColor_V" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>*@
        </td>
        <td style="padding:0px">
            <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The D90Target_U field is required." id="TargetInfo_#__D90Target_U" name="TargetInfo[#].D90Target_U" type="text" value="" />
            @*<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="TargetInfo[#].D90Target_U" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>*@
        </td>
        <td style="padding:0px">
            <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The D90Target_V field is required." id="TargetInfo_#__D90Target_V" name="TargetInfo[#].D90Target_V" style="text-align:center;" type="text" value="" />
            @*<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="TargetInfo[#].D90Target_V" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>*@
        </td>
        <td style="padding:0px">
            <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The D10Target_U field is required." id="TargetInfo_#__D10Target_U" name="TargetInfo[#].D10Target_U" style="text-align:center;" type="text" value="" />
            @*<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="TargetInfo[#].D10Target_U" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>*@
        </td>
        <td style="padding:0px">
            <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The D10Target_V field is required." id="TargetInfo_#__D10Target_V" name="TargetInfo[#].D10Target_V" style="text-align:center;" type="text" value="" />
            @*<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="TargetInfo[#].D10Target_V" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>*@
        </td>
        <td style="padding:0px">
            <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Thickness field is required." id="TargetInfo_#__Thickness" name="TargetInfo[#].Thickness" style="text-align:center;" type="text" value="" />
            @*<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="TargetInfo[#].Thickness" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>*@
        </td>
        <td style="padding:0px">
            <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The FilmWidth field is required." id="TargetInfo_#__FilmWidth" name="TargetInfo[#].FilmWidth" style="text-align:center;" type="text" value="" />
            @*<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="TargetInfo[#].FilmWidth" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>*@
        </td>
        <td style="padding:0px">
            <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The TargetDate field is required." id="TargetInfo_#__TargetDate" name="TargetInfo[#].TargetDate" style="text-align:center;" type="text" value="" />
            @*<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="TargetInfo[#].TargetDate" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>*@
        </td>
        <td style="padding:0px;vertical-align:top;">
            <img id="imgRemoveTarget" alt="Item Lookup" src="/Content/images/trashcan.png" style="cursor:pointer;width:32px;height:29px;" class="deleteLink" />
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

The jquery code for generating the dynamic row is below:

```
  var form = $('#tttt'); // or use the id if you have given the form an id
  var newrow = $('#newrow');
  var tablebody = $('#tbTargetDetailsBody'); // modify to suit your id

  $("#btnTestRow").click(function () {

  var index = (new Date()).getTime(); // unique indexer
  var clone = newrow.clone(); // clone the new row
  clone.html($(clone).html().replace(/#/g, index)); // update the indexer of the clone

  var row = clone.find('tr');
  tablebody.append(row);


  // Reparse the validator
  form.data('validator', null);
  $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
```

Right now i want to add data inside the table depending on data in the db. Below is my code:

```
 fnAddTargetInfo = function (RequestNumberitem, FormID) {
        jQuery.getJSON(
           "/SECEditors/fnGetTargetInfo/", { ReqNo: RequestNumberitem },
             function (data) {
                 if (data != null) {

                     jQuery.each(data, function (i, valTarget) { //already get the data insie db
                        // need to loop the table and put the db data inside the dynamic textbox


                         // Reparse the validator
                         FormID.data('validator', null);
                         $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(FormID);
                     });
                 }
             }
         );
    }
```

Really appreciate your guys help. Thank you.

Comment: The #newrow and #tbTargetDetailsBody are two different tables?

Comment: yes..#tbTargetDetailsBody is the header that #newrow will be add

Comment: What you actually need to do is just add a tr you don't need to add the whole table, just take one row and add that row to the #newrow table

Comment: can i know how to put the db value inside the #newrow textbox?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose this is one of your many cells

```
<td style="padding:0px">
        <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The TargetColor_U field is required." id="TargetInfo_#__TargetColor_U" name="TargetInfo[#].TargetColor_U" type="text" value="" />
        @*<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="TargetInfo[#].TargetColor_U" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>*@
        <input type="hidden" name="TargetInfo.Index" value=# />
    </td>
```

What you need to do is give every input an identifier class (or id, but I prefer class) so the resulting td will be like this

```
<td style="padding:0px">
        <input class="form-control txtColor" data-val="true" data-val-required="The TargetColor_U field is required." id="TargetInfo_#__TargetColor_U" name="TargetInfo[#].TargetColor_U" type="text" value="" />
        @*<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="TargetInfo[#].TargetColor_U" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>*@
        <input type="hidden" name="TargetInfo.Index" value=# />
    </td>
```

Make sure you are inserting the row. In your jQuery iteration you need to call this as follows:

```
jQuery.each(data, function (i, valTarget) { 
          var row = clone.find('tr');  
          var txtColor =  row.find('input.txtColor'); // or find('.txtColor')
          txtColor.val(valTarget.TargetColor_U);
          FormID.data('validator', null);
          $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(FormID);
 });
```